# Google Sheets - Average duration in dataset

Tags: google-sheets, statistics, formula

I am trying to evaluate some information from an animal studying exercise using Google Sheets. I have listed what activity the animal is doing and for how long for.

I just need to figure the formula out to show the average duration per activity from the list.

ie

- Activity | Average Duration
- Climbing | 2
- Sleeping | 6
- Grooming | 6

It sounds relatively simple however I can't think how as the list in column D has different activities. I'm thinking I need to create an array from the dataset and then count the average of the duration???

The Google Sheets is a COPY of my work and is editable. I have highlighted in YELLOW the bit I need help with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11laOfPr3HOQnrkpmVevSOeWncfwnQf6R4lj7cndSDPI/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I misunderstood the ask here, but would placing the following formula in I2 work: `=AVERAGEIF(D:D,F2,C:C)`? You would just need to drag down the formula so it works for the other activities.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly it. I was over complicating. Thanks!